# Remove elements from List that are missing in another list

Tags: list, flutter

I would like to remove from List a elements that are not in another List. Suppose I have

```
List a = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 7},]

List b = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 7},]
```

Then I would like to remove from List a the element `{"id": 4}`, since it is missing in List b

If List b were

```
List b = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 4},]
```

then I would like to remove from List a element `{"id": 7}`

How to do this in Flutter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like this

```
List a = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 7}];
List b = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 7}];

a.removeWhere((elementA) => b.every((elementB) =>              
              elementB["id"] != elementA["id"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  var a = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 7}];
  var b = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 7}];
  var c = a.map((m) => m['id']);
  var d = b.map((m) => m['id']);
  var e = c.toSet().difference(d.toSet());
  var f = a.where((m) => e.contains(m['id']));
  
  print(f);
}
```

Result

```
({id: 4})
```

Comment: I did this a.removeWhere((elementA) => b.every((elementB) =>              
              elementB["id"] != elementA["id"])); because I needed a without the elements missing from b, not a without the elements in b. I hope it is ok